# chrome.webRequest redirect data-URLs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to redirect request to a data-url.

```js
// background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    const url = details.url

    if(url == 'http://www.example.com') {
      return {
        redirectUrl: 'data:application/json; charset=utf-8,' + JSON.stringify({"a":1, "b": 2})
      }
    }

    return {cancel: false}
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]
)
```

Now, I start a ajax in a page:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
// xhr.withCredentials = true
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com', true)
xhr.send()
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText)
      }
  }
}
```

It show's `{"a":1, "b": 2}`.

But, If I add withCredentials, it's error:

[image]

images content:

Fetch API cannot load data:application/json; charset=utf-8,{"a":1,"b":2}. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

How to fix it?

I tried add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header in `onHeadersReceived`, but it's no effect.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function (details) {
      if(details.url == 'http://www.example.com') {
        details.responseHeaders.forEach(header => {
          if(header.name == 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin') {
          header.value = 'null'
        }
      })

      details.responseHeaders.push({
        name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
        value: 'true'
      })
    }

    return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["responseHeaders","blocking"]
)
```

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/191), maybe it is an issue with assigning a header in config.headers with a null value on application start (it pulls a value out of local storage, and initially, nothing is there). Assigning the value to be an empty string when the value is null solves the problem. Here's another related [link](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/251) which might help.

Comment: Please add code, *errors* and data as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/*errors*/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/*error*/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/*errors*/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/*error*/data.

Comment: @Makyen I add text.

Comment: This actually sounds like something Chrome should support doing; a feature request is a good idea.